# If $F_n(x)$ converges in distribution to $G(x)$, and $x_n \to x$, then does $F_n(x_n)$ converges in distribution to $G(x)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, convergence, asymptotics

I'm having some trouble verifying the following line from *Extremes and Related Properties of
Random Sequences and Processes* by Leadbetter:

> If (1.2.1)' and (1.2.3)' hold, then obviously so does (1.2.2)'  [image]

With $F'_n(x)$ converging weakly to $G(x)$ and $\alpha_n' \to a$ and $\beta'_n \to b$, it's clear that $F'_n(ax+b) \to G(ax+b)$ weakly. However, why should $F_n'(\alpha'_n x+ \beta'_n)$ converge weakly to $G(ax+b)$? Since $F_n'$ may not be continuous, it seems we cannot guarantee the convergence even though $\alpha'_n x + \beta'_n \to ax+b$.

Comment: Phil, could you cite the source you took the snapshot of? It's appreciable if you mention the source alongside the image/snap.

Comment: @User1865345 sure it's added now

Comment: Thanks for the citation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285133/show-that-px-n-leq-x-n-rightarrow-px-leq-x

Answer (score 0):

If $X_n \to X$ in distribution and $b_n \to b$, then we may pick $Y_n = X_n$ in distribution for $1 \leq n \leq \infty$ with $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely.

Clearly ,$Y_n + b_n \to Y + b$ almost surely, so $X_n + b_n \to X+b$ in distribution.

We can prove the same thing for $a_n X_n \to aX$, which means $\frac{X_n - \alpha
'}{\beta_n'} \to \frac{X-a}{b}$ in distribution.